# Indonesia language pack for Magento CE 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, language, language-package

I need an Indonesia language pack to integrate with my Indonesian site for one of my Indonesian clients. I found the beta version on the Magento website it is not working fine.

If anyone has an Indonesian verson please share it with me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**Indonesian (Indonesia) Language Pack - Magento**

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-community-modules-indonesian-indonesia-language-pack.html
- https://github.com/bippo/magento-id

Comment: Hi Rahul
Thanks for giving reply. I tried the extension which you given but it is not working in Magento 1.9 version.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the desired translation through Magento connect via admin.
2. Once installed Go to: System -> Manage Stores -> Create store view. Enter the data and save.
3. Now go to: Configuration -> Current Configuration Scope (Select your language from the dropdown) and on the right side under “Locale options” choose the desired language.